# How do i dispatch an action without building a widget in flutter redux?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-redux

Im trying to dispatch actions based in events, i couldn't find any way to achieve that with out returning a widget. here is the default way of doing it

```
   StoreConnector<MyAppState,ActionFunc>(
    converter:(store) => () => store.dispatch(myaction),
    builder:(ctx,callback){
    return Center(child:
         RaisedButton(
         onPressed:(){callback();}
         child:,Text("Action !")
      ));
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

I do it in this way:

```
final store = StoreProvider.of<AppState>(buildContext);
store.dispatch(UserLogOutAction(buildContext);
```

Documentation says following:
A method that can be called by descendant Widgets to retrieve the Store from the StoreProvider.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `middleware` and listing to the event and dispatch action from there.